# Flex - Use id that's stocked on a variable

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder, identifier

I'm new at working with Flex, and I can't figure out how to reuse a specific ID.

So I'm doing an application where you can customize a product. First you choose the product, and then you can add custom text to it.

I can get it to add the text, I add an ID, and when I click on the text I can move it and edit it. My problem is that I can't figure out how to save the edit.

I put the text ID in a hidden field, but I can't use it to replace the text in my field. How could I do that ?

Here's part of my code :

```
<s:TextInput includeIn="modifierTexte" x="24" y="39" width="599" id="idTextePersonnalise"/>
    <mx:RichTextEditor id="persoContentModifier" 
                       backgroundColor="#ccffcc" 
                       title="Texte personnalisé" 
                       x="23.8" y="62.2" width="768" height="200" chromeColor="#A6A3A3" verticalAlign="top"
                       creationComplete="removeMiscButtons()"
                       dropShadowVisible="false" includeIn="modifierTexte"/>
    <s:Button x="571" y="269.4" width="221" height="34" fontFamily="Georgia" fontSize="15" color="#404040" chromeColor="#A8D009" focusColor="#3F9020" id="editTxtToBathtub" label="Modifier le texte" includeIn="modifierTexte" click="editTextToBathtub()"/>
```

So the textinput contains my text id, richTextEditor gets the custom text and you click the button to save.

My function looks like this :

```
private function editTextToBathtub():void{
                var idDeMonTexte:String = idTextePersonnalise.text;
//I'ld like to do something like idDeMonTexte.text = persoContentModifier.text;
            }
```

Everytime I try to use my var to put my richtext back in my custom text, it gives me an error of course...

Anyone know how to work with this ? 
Thanks for your help !

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you're trying to apply an HTML hack (hidden text fields, yuck) to somethng that doesn't need it. Perhaps "data binding" is what you need?

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to look around to see what it is and how to use it. Like I said I'm quite new to this language, I know PHP and HTML really well so I guess I'm trying to replicate what I know.

Answer (score 0):

2 problems.. You say you want to do something like idDemonText.text = personContentModifier.text, but you have no component with an id of idDemonText. (at least not in your example).

The other is you've named your private function the same as the id of your button.  That's probably gonna cause your error. What is your error?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Here's the error I get : 1119: Access of possibly undefined property text through a reference with static type String. I understand this error, but what I need to do is get the content of idDeMonTexte and use the content as an ID. So my var could get the value "myVar3" and this is the ID of the text I need to edit. (The program should read myVar3.text = persoContentModifier.text but I need to find the id dynamically). I have nothing with the id "idDeMonTexte". Sorry if it's not clear, English is not my first language and this is quite complex to explain

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you want.. Like RIAstar says, you're trying a horrible html hack which isn't supported.  You should consider an alternative approach.

Why don't you change your function to this?:

```
private function editTextToBathtub():void{

            persoContentModifier.text = idTextePersonnalise.text;


        }
```